# Romanian fonts in `bibtex`

Tags: bibtex

I need romanian characters ş and ţ in citations. For this I updated chicago style (`chicago.bst` file) and for et. al. i replaced:

first " ş.a. " but i got ?.a. instead
second " \cb{s}.a." but i get the following error

```
\cb{s}.a.}{2007}]{Li2007a}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.[/code]
```

The WME is:

```
\documentclass[oneside,romanian]{scrbook}
\usepackage[]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\cite{Li2007a,RouxSmart:95,Schwind:96,Wood1996,Haff1996}

\bibliographystyle{chicagoro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}\bibliography{D:/JURNALE/a,articles,D:/JURNALE/b}

\end{document}
```

[link to bib file](http://www.geomorphologyonline.com/b.bib)

[link to modified chicago style](http://www.geomorphologyonline.com/chicagoro.bst)

I tried in `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`, `utf8x` and `latin1` without succes.
Because I use LyX and because I have limited time I cannot use `biblatex`.

Edit: the result of the combelow \cb{s} command

[image: combelow \cb{s} command]

Any clue would help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the specific "accent" created by the `\cb` command. Separately, which package defines the `\cb` macro? The error message you report indicates that the macro isn't recognized by LaTeX (or BibTeX), which could be because you didn't load all required packages.

However, as long as the `\cb` command is (properly) defined somewhere, you should be in business, as far as BibTeX is concerned, if you type `{\cb s}` instead of `\cb{s}` in bibliographic entries. (You can keep using `\cb{s}` in the remainder of the document.)

When it comes to sorting entries via BibTeX's mechanisms, words containing `{\cb s}` will be sorted as if the accented s-character were a "plain" `s` (without the accent). If this is *not* what you want, you'll probably have to use biblatex and biber instead of BibTeX.

Comment: I founded the comand on Wikipedia, but now i identified also the package. This is combelow. Entering \usepackage{combelow} now render the comma under s, but is placed not centered, but on the left (see the image in the main article).

Comment: Well, i introduced a space ({ s}), and that created the mistake. Using \cb{s} in the .bst file indeed resolve the problem and the citations are produced with the proper (actually using a trick, so not very proper) romanian characters. Thank for the clue!

Comment: @mihainiculita - Thanks for these additional explanations. Incidentally, have you tried the "cedilla" `\c` diacritic?

Comment: The cedilla is not covered by the package combelow. This package support only comma under and upper.